# The exact current Halachic status of Bar Mitzvah celebratory meal?

Tags: halacha, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53666/when-did-the-bar-mitzvah-ceremony-originate-and-when-did-it-take-on-its-current) brings sources for celebrating Bar Mitzvah by arranging a Seuda.

However I'd like to know what's its current Halachic status - is it mentioned in Poskim, Shu"A, Shu"a Harav etc and how serious it is.

---

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1739/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75951/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53666/759

Comment: The second question was close, but it asks explicitly about *the earliest mentioning of BM*, not the current Halachic status. I asked what *severity of obligation it has* - Rishonim, Achronim, MB or just a good tradition,  or not at all

Comment: I rewrote it to be very specific, thank you.